# Why "should" following "It wouldn't be at all strange..."?

Tags: conditionals

Why did the writer use *should* before the word *find* here?

> It would not be at all strange if some obscene words and gestures **should** find expression.....There was considerable humour, very broad humour too, but nothing obscene.

Why didn’t he write it like this?

- It would not be at all strange if some obscene words and gestures found expression.

Comment: They're both correct; the former is in a more formal, perhaps academic, register.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin 

Comment: Funny you should ask!

Comment: What did you mean by it @tchrist?